# Ultra precision when calling methods in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, timing

I'm programming an app on ios with xcode and I after a lot of work I found out that the functionality is really dependant on the accuracy of the methods calls.
Calling them one line after the other in the code doesn't help, they're still called at up tp 150 ms difference after each other.
So I need to make two methods run at the minimal time difference, hence "at the same time".
These two tasks I'm performing are actually audio and video ones so I understand it might include also in-process latency and delays, so I was wondering maybe you guys would have any isight on how to sync an audio task and a video task so that they start running together, with a very tiny time gap.
I tried using dispatch queues and stuff like that, but they don't work.

I'll be happy to elaborate if I wasn't clear enough.
Thanks!

Comment: GCD dispatch is not meant to be used to sync audio and video

Comment: Apple has APIs specifically to do this.  Read them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make an interrupt driven, multi-tasking OS behave like a realtime OS.

It just doesn't work that way.

You'll need to use the various multimedia APIs to set up a context of playback where the audio and video are synchronized within (which I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

Apple has APIs and documentation to go with them on syncing audio and video.  http://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Obviously calling methods sequentially (serially) won't do what you are asking since each method call will take some finite amount of time, during which time the subsequent methods will be blocked.

To run multiple general-purpose tasks concurrently (potentially truly simultaneously on a modern multi-core device) you do need threading via "dispatch queues and stuff like that."  GCD most certainly *does* work, so you are going to need to elaborate on what you mean by "they don't work."

But this is all probably for naught, because you aren't talking about general-purpose tasks.  If you are handling audio and video tasks, you really shouldn't do all this with your own code on the CPU; you *need* hardware acceleration, and Apple [provides frameworks to help](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/audio-and-video.html).  I'd probably start by taking a look at the [AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) framework, then, depending on what you are trying to do (you didn't really say in your question...) take a look at, variously, [OpenAL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2199/_index.html), [Core Video](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreVideo/CVProg_Intro/CVProg_Intro.html), and [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html).  (There's a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848) out on the latter that's getting rave reviews, but I haven't seen it myself and, truth be told, I'm not an A/V developer.)

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, in any multitasking environment (especially on single core devices), you'll not be able to have guarantees on timing between statements you're executing.

However, since you're mentioning playback of audio and video, Apple does provide some fundamentals that can accomplish this through its frameworks.

**[AVSynchronizedlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSynchronizedLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVSynchronizedLayer)** - If some of your video or audio can playback from an [AVPlayerItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayerItem) (which supports a variety of formats), you can build a tree of other events which are synchronized with it, from keyframe animations to other AVPlayerItems.

If multiple audio tracks are what you're looking to in particular, there are some simpler constructs in Core Audio to do that too.

If you can give a more specific example of your needs someone may be able to provide additional ideas.